# "den Umständen entsprechend gut"

Tags: usage, phrase

Ich habe mich heute mal wieder gewundert, wieso ich immer häufiger die folgende Redewendung lese, wenn jemand z. B. einen Unfall hatte, aber nicht schwer verletzt wurde:

> Ihm geht es den Umständen entsprechend gut.

Meines Erachtens ist der Satz falsch, weil ein "guter" Zustand im Falle eines Unfalls nicht "den Umständen entspricht". Nach einem Unfall würde man schließlich eher erwarten, dass es einem schlecht geht. Aber Sätze wie diesen liest und hört man ständig – sogar in vermeintlich seriösen Medien wie "Der Spiegel" oder "Tagesschau".

Entweder sollte es heißen:

> Ihm geht es den Umständen entsprechend.

Nämlich schlecht, weil er einen Unfall hatte. Damit wäre aber nicht enthalten, dass es ihm noch relativ gut geht.

Das, was von den Autoren aber üblicherweise gemeint ist, ist einer der folgenden Sätze:

> In Anbetracht der Umstände geht es ihm gut.
>   Unter Berücksichtigung der Umstände geht es ihm gut.
>   Trotz der Umstände geht es ihm gut.

D. h., eigentlich geht es ihm schlecht – er hatte ja einen Unfall –, aber weil er noch glimpflich davongekommen ist, geht es ihm *relativ* gut.

Sehe ich da was falsch, bin ich der Einzige, der das so sieht? Woher kommt diese m. E. falsche Verwendung?

Comment: Sehe ich ganz genau so. Eigentlich Blödsinn, wird aber sehr häufig verwendet.

Comment: @Daniel Danke! Ich bin wenigstens nicht alleine... ;-)

Comment: Bemerkenswerterweise gibt es die umgekehrte Nutzung wohl nicht (Beispielsweise: habe gerade im Lotto gewonnen, habe aber einen Schnupfen - da sage ich nicht "Es geht mir den Umständen entsprechend schlecht")

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Da ist was dran! So hab ich das noch gar nicht gesehen. :)

Comment: Gut beobachtet. Eigentlich müsste es *den Umständen widersprechend gut* heißen.

Comment: Der Ausdruck wurde von Ärzten übernommen. Im Arztbereich macht der Audruck Sinn. Wenn ein Unfallopfer medizinisch versorgt wurde und akute Gefahren gebannt wurden, so dass das Unfallopfer nur noch Zeit für die Regenerierung braucht, kann der Arzt sagen, es geht ihm den Umständen entsprechend gut. Das heißt, alles ist medizinisch im Griff, der Verletzte ist auf dem Weg der Genesung und hat keine Schmerzen (auch wenn er einen gebrochenen Fuß hat).

Comment: Der Ausdruck ist völlig in  Ordnung und keineswegs widersprüchlich. Aber: Wenn man __irgendetwas__ lange genug hin- und herwälzt , wird es schräg. Ist aber __nur in Deinem Kopf__. Beachte: 'gut' und 'schlecht' sind keine Absoluta sondern sinf Adjektive mit vielen und vielerlei Abstufungen!

Answer (score 7):

> "Den Umständen entsprechend"

und

> "Den Umständen entsprechend gut"

sind denke ich sehr unterschiedlich, Letzteres bedeutet meiner Auffassung nach "für diese Umstände besser als üblich/über dem Durchschnitt", z. B. keine Schmerzen, weniger Schmerzen, Schmerzen nur bei Bewegung etc. – und in diesem Kontext macht es Sinn.

*Den Umständen entsprechend* bedeutet genau das, was Du gesagt hast – also der Durchschnitt bzw. was man erwarten würde.

Comment: "für diese Umstände besser als üblich/über dem Durchschnitt" - Das _meinen_ die Autoren oder Sprecher üblicherweise damit, ja. Aber meine These ist, dass die Verwendung falsch ist - aus oben genannten Gründen.

Comment: @gehho: ich denke, dass die Verwendung nachvollziehbar und in Ordnung ist.

Answer (score 4):

[Mit Googles n-Gram-Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=den+Umst%C3%A4nden+entsprechend+gut&year_start=1800&corpus=20&smoothing=3) kann man sehen, dass die Wendung "den Umständen entsprechend gut" in exakt dieser Schreibung um 1900 erstmals in der deutschsprachigen Literatur aufgetaucht ist und seit ca. 1970 zunehmend populär wurde. Die Wendung ["den Umständen entsprechend"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=den+Umst%C3%A4nden+entsprechend+gut%2Cden+Umst%C3%A4nden+entsprechend&year_start=1800&corpus=20&smoothing=3) ist dagegen 70-80 Jahre älter und hatte 1900 bereits ihren Höhepunkt erreicht. Ihre Bedeutung lässt sich ganz klar aus dem Sinn der einzelnen Worte ableiten. Wenn man sagt, es gehe jemandem "den Umständen entsprechend", so heißt das, es geht ihm so, wie man das nach den Umständen erwarten würde.

Wenn man dagegen sagt, es gehe jemandem "den Umständen entsprechend gut", so meint man damit, dass es ihm gemessen an den Umständen gut geht. Das ist vom Sinn der Einzelworte nicht gedeckt und stößt mir auch immer wieder mal auf. Das Problem erkennt man vielleicht am deutlichsten, wenn man versucht, die praktisch nichtexistente Wendung "den Umständen entsprechend schlecht" zu interpretieren. Es ist nämlich a priori unklar, ob das auf der Basis von "den Umständen entsprechend" zu interpretieren ist (also: schlecht, wie den Umständen nach auch zu erwarten) oder als Gegenteil von "den Umständen entsprechend schlecht" (also: gemessen an den Umständen schlecht). Wenn die Umstände schlecht sind, ist das nur ein subtiler Unterschied. Sind sie gut, ist es ein erheblicher Unterschied.

Redewendungen, deren Bedeutung sich nicht direkt aus dem Wortsinn erschließt, und die diesem womöglich sogar widersprechen, sind nichts Ungewöhnliches. Meistens fangen sie mit einer ganz geradlinig ableitbaren Bedeutung an und verselbstständigen sich erst später. Wie war das in diesem Fall?

Ein Blick auf frühe Treffer für die Wendung in Google Books hilft uns weiter. Dort finden wir nämlich zweimal ein Komma: "den Umständen entsprechend, gut". (Leider hat der n-Gram-Viewer den Bug, dass man zwar nach Wortfolgen mit Punkt oder Semikolon suchen kann, aber nicht nach solchen mit Komma - auch nicht mit Tricks.) Diese Variante kam schon deutlich früher vor, scheint aber heute kaum noch üblich zu sein:

> Er hatte sich auf eine Gehirnentzündung vorbereitet und sieht nun, dass er darum kommt. Auch Sellien geht es, den Umständen entsprechend, gut; ich kann heute mit leichterem Herzen zurückreiten, als die Tage vorher. (Friedrich Spielhagen, "Was die Schwalbe sang", Die Gartenlaube 1872)
>
> Im Juli 1890 lebt er noch bei klarem Bewusstsein. Sein Zustand den Umständen entsprechend, gut, Hemianopisch. (Salomon Eberhard Henschen, Klinische und anatomische Beiträge zur Pathologie des Gehirns, 1890)

In dem alten Gartenlaube-Fund von 1872 ist zunächst nicht klar, ob das schon die moderne Wendung ist oder wörtlich zu verstehen. Dazu brauchen wir etwas Kontext: Assessor Sellien war nach einem Unfall in Lebensgefahr. Als Gotthold (der einer Gehirnentzündung Entkommene) ihn am Krankenbett besuchte und von dem Verlust einer großen Summe Geldes hörte, fiel er in Ohnmacht und musste gleich daneben gelegt werden. Da nichts in den Umständen darauf hindeutet, dass es Sellien jetzt gut gehen sollte, dürfte also bereits das moderne "den Umständen entsprechend gut" gemeint sein.

Auch der Fund von 1890 scheint so gemeint zu sein. Man könnte spekulieren, dass "den Umständen entsprechend, gut" vielleicht ursprünglich Ärztejargon war. Es liegt schließlich nahe, in einer Krankenakte den Zustand eines Kranken zunächst mit "den Umständen entsprechend" zu beschreiben und dann ggf. nachträglich "gut" oder "schlecht" zu ergänzen, wenn er sich eher im oberen oder eher im unteren Bereich der gewöhnlichen Schwankung befindet. Das könnte dann zu Ärztejargon werden, wobei man im Umgang mit Patienten und Angehörigen das "schlecht" ggf. zensierte. Auf diese Weise hätte dann nur "den Umständen entsprechend, gut" seinen Weg in die Allgemeinsprache gefunden, unterstützt von der Nähe zu "gemessen an den Umständen, gut".

Answer (score 2):

> Meines Erachtens ist der Satz falsch, weil ein "guter" Zustand im Falle eines Unfalls nicht "den Umständen entspricht".

AFAIK the phrase implies that somebody is okay, implicating that it could be worse.

I think that it should not be understood in the sense:

> good as the circumstances implicate.

One can rephrase the sentence to

> Ihm geht es gut, entsprechend den Umständen.

so *entsprechend den Umständen* determines more precisely what *gut* actually means here.

If adverse circumstances are given, **even conditions which usually are considered *bad* are** - given the circumstances - **considered *good***.

Thus *gut* does not really mean good as in healthy and lively but maybe someone cannot walk right now (bad) but he's not in a critical condition.

Comment: "Ihm geht es gut, entsprechend den Umständen." is still wrong in my opinion. It should read "Ihm geht es gut, _trotz_ der Umstände."

Comment: @gehho well, that's comprehensible and would mean the same. Maybe the point is that in that sense the `Umstände` refer to his state (it should be bad according to them), whereas in fact it refers to the classification of `gut`. `Gut` is relative and if something could be worse, even to a commonly as `schlecht` considered condition can be refered as `gut`. Note also that `den Umständen entsprechend` comes right before `gut` which fortifies my theory, that it refers to it that way.

Comment: I fear I cannot follow your theory how `Umstände` could refer to `gut`. Anyway, I think this discussion won't lead anywhere. There seem to be different positions regarding that phrase; and I will try to accept that.

Comment: His point seems to be that we should interpret it as follows. Die Definition von "Gut" wird entsprechend den Umständen vorgenommen. He feels: good, defined according /relative to the circumstances; ie "good" as opposed "bad", the top (good) portion of the goodness scale would be set near his current state, the bottom (bad) end to a state much worse than he is in now.

Answer (score 2):

Im Duden Band 2 – *Das Stilwörterbuch* (2010) findet man tatsächlich den Ausdruck **„dem Patienten geht es den Umständen entsprechend gut“,** was zunächst lediglich bestätigt, dass dieser Ausdruck im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch vorkommt.

In Duden – *Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* sowie in Duden – *Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* steht dagegen nur **„dem Patienten geht es den Umständen entsprechend“** mit der Bedeutung „so gut, wie es in seinem Zustand möglich ist“.

Im Duden-Oxford – *Großwörterbuch Englisch* stehen beide Ausdrücke, wobei die Form mit *gut* als umgangssprachlich gekennzeichnet ist:

> **den Umständen entsprechend** as one would expect [in *or* under the circumstances];
>
> **den Umständen entsprechend gut** (ugs.) as well as can be expected [given the circumstances];

Vermutlich handelt es sich bei „den Umständen entsprechend gut“ um eine Kontamination (Wortkreuzung oder Wortmischung), d. h. eine Zusammenziehung von Wörtern oder Wendungen, die formal und inhaltlich verwandt sind, ähnlich wie der nicht korrekte Ausdruck „meines Erachtens nach“:

> *dem Patienten geht es den Umständen entsprechend gut*
>   dem Patienten geht es den Umständen entsprechend
>   dem Patienten geht es gut
>
> *meines Erachtens nach*
>   meines Erachtens
>   meinem Erachten nach

Allerdings können Kontaminationen über die Umgangssprache ihren Weg in die überregionale Standardsprache finden. So wurden beispielsweise auch die älteren Kontaminationen „auf etwas drängen“, „seit jeher“ und „vorwiegend“ von Sprachpflegern kritisiert, gelten aber heute als korrekt.

Answer (score 1):

Es sagt ja niemand, dass man "considering" mit "berücksichtigend" und "corresponding" mit "entsprechend" übersetzen muss. Tatsächlich findet sich z.B. bei dict.cc unter "considering" auch "entsprechend" als Übersetzung. Wenn du dich also an den beiden englischen Formulierungen gegenüber den deutschen störst, ist das schonmal der falsche Ansatz, wortwörtliche Übersetzungen funktionieren nicht.

Ansonsten verstehe ich nicht recht, was dich an der Formulierung stört. Wenn jemand sich ein Bein gebrochen hat und deshalb im Bett liegen muss, geht es ihm so gesehen nicht gut, denn er kann ja nichts machen und ist nicht gesund. Aber wenn das gebrochene Bein das einzige ist und es ihm *ansonsten* gut geht, geht es ihm eben *den Umständen entsprechend* gut, also letztendlich unter *Ausschluss* des Beinbruchs. Tatsächlich findest du häufig auch die Formulierung *den Umständen entsprechend*, womit aber immer eigentlich das implizite "gut" gemeint ist.

Comment: Was OP meint, ist mir auch erst beim zweiten Hinschauen aufgefallen. "Den Umständen *entsprechend*" heißt eigentlich "mir geht's es genau so gut(oder schlecht) wie es unter den Umständen zu erwarten ist". Mein Zustand entspricht dem Umstand. Wenn du dir ein Bein gebrochen hast, kann es dir nicht gut gehen; also zumindest nicht so gut, wie wenn dein Bein gesund ist. Es muss also zumindest weniger gut sein, was aber somit nicht gut ist ;) Verwirrend?!

Comment: Deswegen ist es ja auch eigentlich "den Umständen entsprechend gut" und "den Umständen entsprechend" impliziert immer "gut". Mir wäre jedenfalls nicht bekannt, wo jemand mit der zweiten Formulierung "schlecht" meint.

Comment: OK, den Vergleich mit dem Englischen habe ich rausgenommen, weil er tatsächlich hinkt. Aber in Folgendem stimme ich dir absolut nicht zu: "...geht es ihm eben den Umständen entsprechend gut". Wenn jemand ein Bein gebrochen hat, dann ist das (üblicherweise) ein schlechter Umstand - ich denke, da sind wir uns einig. Ich finde, es geht ihm dann "den Umständen _widersprechend_ gut". Denn die Umstände sind schlecht, aber ihm geht es trotzdem relativ gut. "Den Umständen entsprechend gut" kann es einem nur gehen, wenn man keinen Unfall hatte - wenn nämlich die Umstände gut sind.

Comment: "Mir wäre jedenfalls nicht bekannt, wo jemand mit der zweiten Formulierung "schlecht" meint." - Oh doch: "Peters Mutter ist gestern gestorben." - "Oh nein, und wie geht es ihm?" - "Naja, den Umständen entsprechend eben." Das ist meines Erachtens auch die richtige Verwendung der Redewendung "den Umständen entsprechend". Nämlich "genau so gut (oder schlecht) wie es unter den Umständen zu erwarten ist" - wie von OregonGhost richtig festgestellt.

Comment: Aber wenn Peters Mutter gestorben ist und ich sage, dass es ihm den Umständen entsprechend geht, meine ich damit doch ebenfalls, dass es ihm - abgesehen davon, dass er trauert - gut geht. Der Schlüssel zum Verständnis der Entsprechung liegt aus meiner Sicht darin, dass es den jeweiligen Umstand eigentlich aus der Betrachtung ausschließt. Das mag aufgrund der verwendeten Worte zwar nicht logisch erscheinen, aber wann ist Sprache schon logisch. Jedenfalls würde ich in diesem Fall definitiv nicht meinen, dass es ihm schlecht geht - das würde ich dann explizit formulieren.

Comment: Wenn Peter wegen Peters Mutter sich "den Umständen entsprechend" fühlt, geht's ihm schlicht weg sch***e. Von gut kann da nicht die Rede sein. Sagt man "den Umständen entsprechend **gut**" meint man, ihm geht es besser als zu erwarten war und das ist semantisch falsch – zumindest laut OP und inzw. auch meiner Meinung nach.

Comment: @Em1: Verstehe und akzeptiere was du meinst, sehe es jedoch komplett anders.

Comment: @OregonGhost Fair enough. Ich wollte nur noch mal die andere Sicht argumentieren. – Der erste Abschnitt deiner Antwort ist übrigens inzw. obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Selbstverständlich kommen solche "Kontaminationen" vor, und in einer lebendigen Sprache ist nicht immer alles streng logisch. Bei der hier zur Debatte stehenden Verwendung von "entsprechend" handelt es sich aber nicht nur um eine Formulierung, die "eigentlich" falsch ist. Vielmehr wüsste man, da ja die "richtige" Verwendung von "entsprechend" noch existiert, überhaupt nicht mehr, was denn nun gemeint ist. Wenn es einerseits einem Bergsteiger, der trotz vieler Knochenbrüche mit dem Leben davon kam, "den Umständen entsprechend gut geht" und andererseits sein Arzt, der ihn zusammengeflickt hat, "seiner Leistung entsprechend gut bezahlt wird", dann drückt die gleiche Formulierung ihren korrekten Sinn und das Gegenteil davon aus. Das kann nicht Sprachgebrauch werden. Was die DUDEN-Redaktion geritten hat, als sie den Patienten-Satz in ihr Werk aufnahm, weiß der Sprachteufel allein...

Answer (score 0):

Wenn man das Wort „gut“ wörtlich nimmt, gebe ich dir vollkommen Recht. Diese Aussage ist dann einfach nur Blödsinn.

In dem Kontext nimmt das Wort aber – meiner Meinung nach – eine etwas andere Bedeutung ein, die mir gerade schwerfällt in Worte zu fassen. Wie wenn man fragt

> Wie gut geht es dir heute?

Das ist eine Frage noch dem Wohlbefinden. Man könnte „gut“ durch „schlecht“ ersetzen, und der Sinn der Frage bliebe derselbe. Das „gut“ mein hier nur die **Einstufung auf der Skala des Wohlbefindens**, genau so, wie es „schlecht“ in der Frage meinen würde.
Die Antwort auf die Frage lautet also

> Den Umständen entsprechend gut

Das „gut“ ist nur eine (eventuell unnötige) Ergänzung, um die Frage zu präzisieren und auszudrücken, dass man nach dem Wohlbefinden fragt. Denn „Wie geht es dir?“ kann auch in Bezug auf andere Zustände des Befindens gemeint sein, wie Ausgeschlafenheit, Hungrigkeit usw. Genauso taucht diese (unnötige) Präzisierung wieder in der Antwort auf, auch wenn es in der Frage vielleicht nicht vorkam.

Comment: _Wenn man das Wort „gut“ wörtlich nimmt_ Das geht aber ja schon nicht, weil es von 'gut' beliebig viele Abstufungen gibt.